# How to make CSS multiline typewriter effect responsive?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, responsive

**Goal & Issue:** I wanted to have a responsive typewriter effect in my header where text would resize and lines would break with the screen. To sorta' achieve that I made each line its own `p` with it's own animation & keyframes, but this isn't responsive. I tired to make the header a flexbox, but it doesn't seem to flex at al--the text goes off screen when I simulate a mobile view. **I don't want to use JavaScript**, so I'm looking to stick with CSS.

**Main Questions**

1. Is it possible to have multi-line typewriter text wrap responsively?
2. Most of the other answers to this question suggested using a flexbox. I've implemented them successfully elsewhere, but I'm having difficulties with this component. What am I doing wrong? Should I use media queries instead and/or alongside a flexbox?

**Small Side Questions**

3. Do I even need `to width: 100%` in my keyframes? With it enabled the cursor runs past the end of the first two lines of text (but not the others).
4. Do I need to define `html` and `body` as `height: 100%` for this component?

---

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/nat-jt/pen/rNedexG and the code:

**HTML:**

```
<header class="header-main">
  {% include nav.html %}
  <!--  Typewriter -->
  <div class="screen">
    <h1 class="anim-typewriter1">_Hi, I'm Natalie</h1>
    <p class="anim-typewriter2">
      _I do user research + ethnography
    </p>
    <p class="anim-typewriter3">
      _I use my background in anthropology + cognitive science to try
    </p>
    <p class="anim-typewriter4">
      & understand the intersections of lived experiences + contexts
    </p>
    <p class="anim-typewriter5">
      _In my work I break complex problems into understandable
    </p>
    <p class="anim-typewriter6">
      components & provide actionable findings
    </p>
  </div>
</header>
```

**SASS:**

```
html.header-main, body.header-main
   height: 100%

header.header-main
   position: relative
   z-index: 1
   display: flex
   flex-direction: column
   align-items: flex-start
   justify-content: flex-start
   width: 100%
   height: 100vh // calc(100vh - 8em)
   min-height: 100%
   padding: 4em
   overflow: hidden
   background-color: rgb(25,25,25)

   h1, p
      position: relative
      top: 25%
      // width: 35em
      // width: 65ch
      border-right: 2px solid $comp-green
      color: rgba(255,255,255,.75)
      font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace
      font-size: 130%
      text-align: left
      white-space: nowrap
      overflow: hidden
      //transform: translateY(-50%)

   h1
      font-size: 250%
      font-weight: 600
      width: 9.05em
      width: 16ch

/* Animation */
.anim-typewriter1
   width: 9.05em
   width: 16ch
   animation: typing1 1.5s steps(16) 350ms 1 normal both

.anim-typewriter2
   width: 18.75em
   width: 33ch
   margin-top: .5em
   opacity: 0
   animation: typing2 2s steps(33) 3s 1 normal both

.anim-typewriter3
   width: 35.7em
   width: 63ch
   margin-top: 1em
   opacity: 0
   animation: typing3 2s steps(63) 5s 1 normal both

.anim-typewriter4
   width: 35.1em
   width: 62ch
   margin-bottom: 1em
   opacity: 0
   animation: typing4 2s steps(62) 7s 1 normal both,cursor_blink .8s steps(44) infinite normal

.anim-typewriter5
   width: 31.7em
   width: 56ch
   margin-top: 1em
   opacity: 0
   animation: typing5 2s steps(56) 9.5s 1 normal both,cursor_blink .8s steps(44) infinite normal

.anim-typewriter6
   width: 22.7em
   width: 40ch
   opacity: 0
   animation: typing6 2s steps(40) 11.5s 1 normal both,cursor_blink .8s steps(44) infinite normal

@keyframes typing1
   from
      width: 0
   to
      width: 100%
   99.9%
      border-right: 2px solid $comp-green
   100%
      border-right: none

@keyframes typing2
   from
      width: 0
   to
      width: 100%
   1%
      opacity: 1
   99.99%
      border-right: 2px solid $comp-green
   100%
      opacity: 1
      border-right: none

@keyframes typing3
   from
      width: 0
   // to
   //    width: 35.7em
   1%
      opacity: 1
   99.99%
      border-right: 2px solid $comp-green
   100%
      opacity: 1
      border-right: none

@keyframes typing4
   from
      width: 0
   // to
   //    width: 35.1em
   1%
      opacity: 1
   99.99%
      border-right: 2px solid $comp-green
   100%
      opacity: 1
      border-right: none

@keyframes typing5
   from
      width: 0
   to
      width: 31.7em
   1%
      opacity: 1
   99.99%
      border-right: 2px solid $comp-green
   100%
      opacity: 1
      border-right: none

@keyframes typing6
   from
      width: 0
   to
      width: 22.7em
   1%
      opacity: 1
   100%
      opacity: 1
 

@keyframes cursor_blink
   from
      border-right-color: $comp-green
   to
      border-right-color: transparent
```

I have seen the other questions related to this issue, and while it helped me clean some things up I still can't work out a solution from their answers.

Thank you for your time & help! Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide.

Comment: I would try doing this with javascript you are repeating alot of code and everytime you add a new line you need to repeat more code, or if you want to change the class names for example your making yourself so much more work

Comment: Maybe check out this link could be helpful: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/11361-typewriter-effect/

Comment: I am not looking to use JavaScript right now, but thank you for the suggestion. I've updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: Fair enough :) Good luck!

Comment: If you're looking for the text to respond to screen size I'd look at using [viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/) for font-size.